# Working with Terraform Workspaces with AWS S3 backend and DynamoDb state lock

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, terraform

I have multi environment setup in different AWS Accounts, Dev, Test & Prod.

I want to start creating `terraform workspace new dev` and have `backend.tf` file point to S3 in Dev.

Now when I switch to new `terraform workspace new test`, how to I configure my backend.tf to point to S3 in Test AWS Account.

Also I need to utilize the DynamoDB feature to lock the tfstate.

Please suggest.

Comment: You can't do this AFAIK. Instead you should use different state configuration with different buckets or instead put the state all in the same S3 bucket (I'd advise the first option).

Comment: Yeah, maybe different backend.tf file which has the new S3. Any reference example please?

Comment: You would need to show what you've done really. The typical thing is to use some form of wrapper script or Terragrunt to set the state file configuration and only hardcode the bits that don't change as partial state configuration. There's a few other examples of how to manage your Terraform code for different environments and accounts etc elsewhere on Stack Overflow.